# clojure: update-in only if all keys present

Tags: clojure

Is there an existing clojure function like `update-in` but only makes changes if all keys are present?

Something that would behave like:

```
(def e1 {"one" "two"})
(def e2 {"one" "two" "three" "four"})

(update-in-if-present e1 ["three"] (fn [x] (str x x)))
;; => {"one" "two"}
(update-in e1            ["three"] (fn [x] (str x x)))
;; => {"one" "two", "three" ""}
(update-in-if-present e2 ["three"] (fn [x] (str x x)))
;; => {"one" "two", "three" "fourfour"}
(update-in e2            ["three"] (fn [x] (str x x)))
;; => {"one" "two", "three" "fourfour"}

(defn update-in-if-present [m [k] f]
```

Here is a simplified version (that only supports a single key) of what I am talking about:

```
(if-not (get m k)
    m
    (update-in m [k] f)))
```

Comment: Do you mean for your examples `e1` and `e2` to be sets `#{}` rather than maps `{}`?  Since you are talking about keys, I think you want a map (which is a keyed structure) but I don't see any `:keys` in your example.

Comment: I mean "keys" in the same sense as the documentation to `update-in`:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in

Comment: Just to be clear, the key to `e1` is "one" since `(first e1)` yields `["one" "two"]` and `(keys e1)` yields `("one")`.  What you have there is neither a conventional map nor set.  Are you just looking to `filter` a collection maybe?

Comment: Correct, in this example, `"one"` is a "key".  `update-in` works on a nested associative structure, but adds missing structure (and it doesn't require keyworks (e.g., :k), just associations).  I'm want the exact same thing except if any keys are missing to just return the existing structure.

Comment: Short answer is "no" there is no existing function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no such function but it is easily defined with a simple `reduce`, for example

```
(defn update-in-if-present
  "Apply f to every k from ks in m if the key is present in m."
  [m ks f]
  (reduce (fn [acc k]
            (if (contains? acc k)
              (update-in acc [k] f)
              acc)) m ks))
```

**Update**
Turns out I misread the question but [here's a link to the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059795/1685739).

Comment: That looks interesting - but what I hoped to say was to only apply the given function to the last key in the sequence.  It should basically operate just like `update-in` except only if all keys in the chain are present.  See Jacob's answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136617/clojure-idiomatic-update-a-maps-value-if-the-key-exists

Comment: You are right, my bad, it seems I overlooked that part in your question, sorry about that (I'm going to add a link to Jacob's answer in mine).